# pySpark is unable to process predictions

Tags: python, machine-learning, pyspark, regression, evaluator

I have a code:

```py
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[indexer, encoder, categorical_assembler,numerical_assembler,standardScaler,final_assembler,regressor1])
train_data, test_data = df.randomSplit([.8,.2], seed=RANDOM_SEED)
model1 = pipeline.fit(train_data)
pred_results = model1.transform(test_data)
results = pred_results.select('prediction', 'median_house_value')
results = results.withColumn('prediction', F.round('prediction'))
display(results.show(5))
```

I works fine.
Then I want to estimate model's metrics:

```
evaluator = RegressionEvaluator(predictionCol="prediction", labelCol="median_house_value")
r2 = evaluator.evaluate(results, {evaluator.metricName: "r2"})
r2
```

And it crushes every time with this error:

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last) Cell In[71], line 6 3 display(HTML(test_data.toPandas().info())) 4 #display(HTML(results.toPandas().info())) 5 # Расчет метрики R2 6 r2 = evaluator.evaluate(results, {evaluator.metricName: "r2"}) 7 r2

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pyspark\ml\evaluation.py:109, in Evaluator.evaluate(self, dataset, params) 107 if isinstance(params, dict): 108     if params: 109         return self.copy(params)._evaluate(dataset) 110     else: 111         return self._evaluate(dataset)

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pyspark\ml\evaluation.py:148, in JavaEvaluator._evaluate(self, dataset) 146 self._transfer_params_to_java() 147 assert self._java_obj is not None 148 return self._java_obj.evaluate(dataset._jdf)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py:1322, in JavaMember.__call__(self, *args) 1316 command = proto.CALL_COMMAND_NAME +\ 1317     self.command_header +\ 1318     args_command +\ 1319     proto.END_COMMAND_PART 1321 answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command) 1322 return_value = get_return_value( 1323     answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name) 1325 for temp_arg in temp_args: 1326     if hasattr(temp_arg, "_detach"):

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pyspark\errors\exceptions\captured.py:169, in capture_sql_exception.<locals>.deco(*a, **kw) 167 def deco(*a: Any, **kw: Any) -> Any: 168     try: 169         return f(*a, **kw) 170     except Py4JJavaError as e: 171         converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py:326, in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name) 324 value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client) 325 if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE: 326     raise Py4JJavaError( 327         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n". 328         format(target_id, ".", name), value) 329 else: 330     raise Py4JError( 331         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}. Trace:\n{3}\n". 332         format(target_id, ".", name, value))

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o2827.evaluate. org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 102.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 102.0 (TID 85) (DESKTOP-9JCLV0J executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: [FAILED_EXECUTE_UDF] Failed to execute user defined function (StringIndexerModel$$Lambda$3713/2049034039: (string) => double).   at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.failedExecuteUserDefinedFunctionError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:217)  at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors.failedExecuteUserDefinedFunctionError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala)   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:760)    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)   at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)   at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)   at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)   at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)   at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1431)   at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:199)     at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.foldLeft$(TraversableOnce.scala:192)    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1431)  at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.aggregate(TraversableOnce.scala:260)    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.aggregate$(TraversableOnce.scala:260)   at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.aggregate(Iterator.scala:1431)     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$treeAggregate$4(RDD.scala:1234)    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$treeAggregate$6(RDD.scala:1235)    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitions$2(RDD.scala:853)     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitions$2$adapted(RDD.scala:853)     at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:364)  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:328)     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:92)   at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:161)     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:139)  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:554)     at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1529)    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:557)    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Unseen label: ISLAND. To handle unseen labels, set Param handleInvalid to keep.     at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexerModel.$anonfun$getIndexer$1(StringIndexer.scala:406)    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexerModel.$anonfun$getIndexer$1$adapted(StringIndexer.scala:391) 32 more

Driver stacktrace:  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2785)     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2721)   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2720)   at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)     at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2720)  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1206)  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1206)  at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1206)     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2984)     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2923)   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2912)   at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:971)   at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2263)    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2358)    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$fold$1(RDD.scala:1172)     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:405)    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.fold(RDD.scala:1166)    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$treeAggregate$2(RDD.scala:1259)    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:405)    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.treeAggregate(RDD.scala:1226)   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$treeAggregate$1(RDD.scala:1212)    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:405)    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.treeAggregate(RDD.scala:1212)   at org.apache.spark.mllib.stat.Statistics$.colStats(Statistics.scala:58)    at org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.RegressionMetrics.summary$lzycompute(RegressionMetrics.scala:70)   at org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.RegressionMetrics.summary(RegressionMetrics.scala:62)  at org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.RegressionMetrics.SSerr$lzycompute(RegressionMetrics.scala:74)     at org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.RegressionMetrics.SSerr(RegressionMetrics.scala:74)    at org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.RegressionMetrics.r2(RegressionMetrics.scala:131)  at org.apache.spark.ml.evaluation.RegressionEvaluator.evaluate(RegressionEvaluator.scala:102)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)  at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)     at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)   at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)     at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)   at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)     at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: [FAILED_EXECUTE_UDF] Failed to execute user defined function (StringIndexerModel$$Lambda$3713/2049034039: (string) => double).  at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.failedExecuteUserDefinedFunctionError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:217)  at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors.failedExecuteUserDefinedFunctionError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala)   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:760)    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)   at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)   at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)   at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)   at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)   at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1431)   at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:199)     at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.foldLeft$(TraversableOnce.scala:192)    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1431)  at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.aggregate(TraversableOnce.scala:260)    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.aggregate$(TraversableOnce.scala:260)   at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.aggregate(Iterator.scala:1431)     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$treeAggregate$4(RDD.scala:1234)    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$treeAggregate$6(RDD.scala:1235)    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitions$2(RDD.scala:853)     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitions$2$adapted(RDD.scala:853)     at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:364)  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:328)     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:92)   at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:161)     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:139)  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:554)     at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1529)    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:557)    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) 1 more Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Unseen label: ISLAND. To handle unseen labels, set Param handleInvalid to keep.    at 
org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexerModel.$anonfun$getIndexer$1(StringIndexer.scala:406)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexerModel.$anonfun$getIndexer$1$adapted(StringIndexer.scala:391)
    ... 32 more
```

I have tested this code on small sample of dataset and it worked. I expect to get something like this:

> 0.6152

It's even more strange, when I run:

```
evaluator = RegressionEvaluator(predictionCol="median_income", labelCol="median_house_value")
display(HTML(test_data.toPandas().info()))
r2 = evaluator.evaluate(test_data, {evaluator.metricName: "r2"})
r2
```

It works without any problems!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem by adding
".setHandleInvalid("keep")". So the working code looks like this:

```
str_cols=['ocean_proximity']
#У нас одна категориальная колонка, превратим её в индексы
indexer=StringIndexer(inputCols=str_cols,outputCols=[c+'_idx' for c in str_cols]).setHandleInvalid("keep")
#Теперь сделаем для всех индексов свои колонки техникой One hot encoding.
encoder = OneHotEncoder(inputCol="ocean_proximity_idx",
                        outputCol="ocean_proximity_ohe")
#Загоним теперь все получившиеся колонки в один вектор
categorical_assembler = \
        VectorAssembler(inputCols=["ocean_proximity_ohe"],
                                        outputCol="categorical_features").setHandleInvalid("keep")
#Преобразуем в вектор числовые переменные
numerical_cols=['longitude','latitude','housing_median_age','total_rooms','total_bedrooms',
                'population','households','median_income']
numerical_assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=numerical_cols,
                                                                            outputCol="numerical_features").setHandleInvalid("keep")
#Стандартизуем получившийся вектор, чтобы ничего не выпирало
standardScaler = StandardScaler(inputCol='numerical_features',
                                                                outputCol="numerical_features_scaled",withMean=True)
all_features = ['categorical_features','numerical_features_scaled']
#А теперь соберём в единый вектор все наши перменные
final_assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=all_features, 
                                  outputCol="features").setHandleInvalid("keep") 
#Построим две модели. В первой используем все данные, во второй - только числовые.
regressor1=LinearRegression(featuresCol='features', labelCol='label')
regressor2=LinearRegression(featuresCol='numerical_features_scaled', labelCol='label')
```